# Float: right property not working in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I'm using a flexbox in my webpage , and I have two elements in it.
I want the first element to be aligned center and the second on to be aligned towards the right. I am able to align them to the center with flexbox properties, but I'm not able to align the second one to the left. `Float: right` doesn't work apparently.
Here's my code:
Html:

```
<div>
<p> Hello </p>
<span> Hey! </span>
</div>
```

Css:

```
div {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
width: 100%;
}

span{
float: right;
}
```

[Here's a fiddle attempt.](https://jsfiddle.net/wo5ps46b/1/)

Answer (score 0):

since you are using flex,it is seeing you justify-content: center;

So you need to write something which overwrites it and which is:

```
span{
justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

to align the right